# Purpose of overriding hashcode for an Entity classs

Tags: android, android-room

I just need some clarification, but is the reason why we are overriding the `hashcode` method, to give each `instance` stored within the `database` a unique address. If that is the case why isn't `hashcode` auto-generated?

I have another question as well this one regarding `Room Databases`, I am aware that some Articles(From News API) do not have an ID, hence I have to find a way to ID the Articles as `Room` requires an ID.

I have tried setting the `URL` as the `Primary Key` however I get this error
`error: There is a problem with the query: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such column: id) public abstract androidx.lifecycle.LiveData<java.util.List<com.example.secondnews.Article>> getAllArticles();`

I then added an `ID` parameter which leads to a crash after clicking around this was the error
`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.Object.hashCode()' on a null object reference`

After asking, I got this as an answer which solves the problem however I cannot wrap my head around it, why are we checking `if(url.isNullOrEmpty())`? I don't think the `Url` will ever be empty hence this line of code will never run `result = 31 * result + url.hashCode()`

```
 override fun hashCode(): Int {
        var result = id.hashCode()
        if(url.isNullOrEmpty()){
            result = 31 * result + url.hashCode()
        }
        return result
    }
```

If the `ID` is null, wouldn't `var result = id.hashCode()` return zero and since the `URL` will never be null, that means we will return zero as a hashcode?

In addition, wouldn't setting the `@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)` result in an autogenerated `ID`? If that is the case how is the `ID` ever null?

**Room Entity**

```
@Entity(
    tableName = "articles", indices = [Index(value = ["url","title"], unique = true)]
    )

@Parcelize
data class Article(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Int? =null,
    val author: String?,
    val description: String?,
    val source: Source?,
    val title: String?,
    val url: String?,
    val urlToImage: String?,
    val publishedAt: String?,
    val content: String?
): Parcelable {
    override fun hashCode(): Int {
        var result = id.hashCode()
        if(url.isNullOrEmpty()){
            result = 31 * result + url.hashCode()
        }
        return result
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When `autoGenerate = true` is coded or even not and just @PrimaryKey with a nullable Integer type is used then the value of the column is generated by SQLite NOT ROOM and is therefore not known until the row is inserted.

The source object will not be changed, BUT the convenience `@Insert` can handle the value being returned as a Long.

With, for example

```
@Dao
interface TheDAO {
    @Insert
    fun insert(article: Article): Long
}
```

You could do something like

```
var myArticle = Article(author = "Fred", .....)
myAricle.id = dao.insert(myArticle).toInt()
```

- where `dao` has been been obtained (instantiated) appropriately

**autoGenerate**

As inferred above it is not autoGenerate being true or not that determines the auto generation of the value. In fact the potential value, for ROOM tables is ALWAYS generated (i.e. SQLite does cater for WITHOUT ROWID tables ROOM does not support their use at the time of writing).

More specifically for tables that do not have WITHOUT ROWID always have a hidden column called **rowid** that is a integer value that is generated by SQLite and which will be 1 greater than the highest rowid in the table (or should the highest possible value have been reached then an unused value).

If a column type is INTEGER (Room uses the INTEGER type for Int, Long, Byte, Boolean ....) and the column is the PRIMARY KEY (aka @PrimaryKey annotation) then that column is an alias of the **rowid** column. If the value is not specified then the rowid will be generated (1 or 1 greater than the highest rowid in the table) as the column is an alias of the rowid it too will have this value.

What `autoGenerate = true` does is to add the SQLite AUTOINCREMENT keyword if the column type is INTEGER.

This adds a constraint/rule that says that the generated must be a higher number and one ever used (without deleting the row with the highest rowid will allow that rowid to be reused).

To facilitate the recording of the highest ever used a system table sqlite_sequence is used where the highest value is stored for each table. ***There are overheads to maintaining such a table.*** The SQLite documentation states:-

- > *The AUTOINCREMENT keyword imposes extra CPU, memory, disk space, and disk I/O overhead and should be avoided if not strictly needed. It is usually not needed.*

You may wish to refer to https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html